# Book in which Las Vegas was previously nuked and a group hides out in it with radiation suit

Tags: story-identification, novel

This was a book I read back in eighth grade, 6 or 7 years ago. The book was at least in the 2000s, if not later. It referenced what seemed to be modern items at the time.

One part of the book included a backstory that explains that Las Vegas was nuked by terrorists, and the main character felt bad for the punishment the United States would dish out to them. Regardless, the main character is on the run, so they decide to hide in the radiation-filled Las Vegas. Most of Las Vegas is destroyed, but they find a nice villa that is still in good condition. They must wear radiation suits while hiding there. This was only one part of the book and not the main story, as the main characters were on the run at this time.

Comment: When were you in eighth grade? Did it seem like a contemporary book then? An older book? Do you remember approximately how many pages the book was? 80? 200? 2000?

Comment: 8th grade was probably 6 or 7 years ago. The book was at least in the 2000's, if not later. It referenced what seemed to be modern items at the time. No idea how long the book was. Multiple characters were involved but of course it was only 1 main character.

Comment: FOUND! It was called "Brainjack" for anyone who was curious.

Comment: You can post that as an answer, or we can post for you. If you post it, you will want as much detail as you can that matches the question, things like plot summaries or your memories of the book. You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour], although a self-answer won't complete until 48 hours after you asked the question.

Comment: I've posted an answer. Feel free to include any details from my answer in your own, and let me know so that I can remove it in favor of yours.

Answer (score 4):

The querent posted that it was Brian Falkner's *[Brainjack](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/7006426)*.

[image: Front cover of Brainjack]

> Las Vegas is gone—destroyed in a terrorist attack. Black Hawk helicopters patrol the skies over New York City. And immersive online gaming is the most dangerous street drug around. In this dystopic near-future, technology has leapt forward once again, and neuro-headsets have replaced computer keyboards. Just slip on a headset, and it’s the Internet at the speed of thought.
>
> For teen hacker Sam Wilson, a headset is a must. But as he becomes familiar with the new technology, he has a terrifying realization. If anything on his computer is vulnerable to a hack, what happens when his mind is linked to the system? Could consciousness itself be hijacked? Before he realizes what’s happened, Sam’s incursion against the world’s largest telecommunications company leads him to the heart of the nation’s cyberdefense network and brings him face to face with a terrifying and unforeseen threat.

From [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1108828858) (emphasis mine):

> The story starts in a big city with a teen in high school. This boy attempts to hack into one of the most secure business franchises in the world. After words, he and his friend use neuro-helmets that allow them to use a computer just by thinking. Then, the hacker gets arrested on the charges of hacking and terrorism. He is then taken to a prison made for hackers, and the like. He then escapes and is recruited by a secret organization that uses elite hackers to help protect the U.S. Very odd and scary things happen that lead three of the hackers to go on the run. They get held up in a mall but escape to the dessert with a hostage. **They drive to Las Vegas, which has been destroyed by a bomb, and they hide there** from a sentient A.I. or Artificial Intelligence that is taking over people’s minds. They are driven out and head southwest. They meet a resistance and then head for a mountain. At that mountain… well you’ll have to read the book to find out.